# Windows OS running in accessibility mode?

Tags: windows, accessibility

How can we detect in Windows OS is running in accessibility mode? What we basically need to check if a user has turned on any accessibility feature when launching an application. Thoughts?

Comment: Windows has a lot of accessibility features. You might want to try narrowing down exactly which your program would be able to react meaningfully to. I mean, the user might have invert colors mode on, but that doesn't necessarily mean you need to do anything about it...

Comment: Yes, but how to detect that the invert colors mode is on? I can't find any relevant documentation/APIs that can help a developer detect such scenarios?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ask the user for what features they want enabled. You shouldn't make assumptions in your app about what they need, since you'll probably be wrong (maybe they're using the magnifier because they are looking at Where's Waldo puzzles).

There's no "Accessibility Mode" in Windows just like there's no "Accessibility Mode" in the real world. Offer the individual features that might be needed to improve accessibility, and let the user decide what's best for them.

Comment: Thanks. We already plan to support most of the accessibility features with a simple user preference screen. What I was looking for was if there was a setting @ the OS level which a user can set to indicate to all applications. If not now, I wish this particular preference soon makes it to the OS settings. It would be easier for people to configure at one place rather than configuring each individual application.